# Image Panorama in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, accelerometer, gyroscope

In my app, i need to take continuous images and make them as panoramic.For that it requires android sensor rotation calculations.Accelerometer pitch,roll,azimuth returns  values based on orientation.But it is not accurate,ie suppose if a image is taken in the beginning as the starting image,then next image should be clicked only after sufficient device rotation.Likewise it should take some 5 - 6 images and make one panoramic image.

Here the problem is:

How to calculate the device rotation(using augmented reality if possible) and take images automatically?

Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: I'd rather go with the sensors, you'd have to use filters to smooth the orientation values and as such have to find a reasonable compromise between possible rotationspeed and smoothness of orientation. When playing around i found my filters implementation could give me stable 1 degree values but for the price of about 2-3 seconds delay.

Comment: @Cdr.Powell i didn't get it.Can you make it some more clear.

Comment: You said sensors are not accurate. That's true, but using different filter algorithms (in my case LowPass and Median) I'm getting orientation values with a precision of 1 degree. But both filters come with a delay, so when turning the device the filters need about 2-3 seconds to catch up with the movement. Maybe by applying more advanced filter algorithms this can be improved. Anyways I guess this is easier to implement than image recognition algorithms to trigger next image by augmented reality.

Comment: @Cdr.Powell  Thanks ..let me check this..if you have any sample reference link,please share with me.

Comment: hi...Have u done auto capturing part using camera??If yes then what have you used??plz help me...

Comment: Hi KP_ , Can you please tell me that what was the SDK/Lib that you used to build your app ? How did you stitch the images ?

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa  i used openCV library.

Comment: Hi @KP_ i need to calculate angle do you have any idea i need to calculate angle from middle to left and middle to right like panaroma i m not saying about azimuth pitch or roll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is actually not about gyroscope, and I don't know if it's still actual for you, but hope it will be helpful for someone.

Panorama feature is already implemented in standard android camera at least since Android 4.0 (perhaps it was available in even earlier versions but I'm not sure, you can check it), so since source code is open for everyone, it might be the easiest way just to copy required functionality.

Although you can download source of apps from https://android.googlesource.com/ (you want LegacyCamera or Camera), you can't just open project of any standard app in Eclipse or other IDE. For example, LegacyCamera depends on Gallery2 and other dependences that might be hard to be resolved.

I spent several days trying to move panorama feature to separate project. You can download it from here: https://github.com/yankeppey/PanoramaSample . Several remarks:

1. Functional core (creating one panorama image from several ones, progress notices, etc) is on native part.
2. I used java code from from LegacyCamera which was used in Android 4.0-4.1, not 4.2, because it was significantly easier for me. Native part is taken from 4.2, it has only minor changes inside and almost the same JNI interfaces.
3. This project is just to help you move panorama feature to your own app, it's not like kind of library, don't expect clean code without bugs, it's just pretty dirty and buggy project. If I have time I'll try to make it cleaner, but there is no warranty :)

Comment: have you make it cleaner and working for Android Studio?